# VS throws run time error while tried to get value from telerik multi combo box value

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I've tried to get *telerik multi combo box value* when user selects a row i want to get it's first column of it

but this run time erro is thrown

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

in the last line of this code

```
  static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

and i've searched everywhere i know waht this run time error is but i don't know how to fix it

this is my code

```
        private void cmbbEmply_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetEmp = (int)cmbbEmply.EditorControl
                               .Rows[cmbbEmply.SelectedIndex].Cells[0].Value;
    }
```

please don't direct me to another page i read all of them and i couldn't understand where my problem is

Comment: SUGGESTION: 1) Go into your MSVS debugger, 2) Set a breakpoint just before the error occurs, 3) *LOOK AT THE VARIABLES* to determine which variable is the uninitialized object

Comment: @paulsm4 how can do step 3??

Comment: [MSDN: autos and locals window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx).  See also: [Debugging in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What is the Value of SelectedIndex in the handler? It might be -1 if no selected row is present, hence, you will get this exception as you can't find row -1 in the rows collection.

Comment: i've checked it  allways has a value,cuase when form loads it will run and when user selects something it will run again

Comment: Then you shoould make sure that cmbbEmply.EditorControl                               .Rows[cmbbEmply.SelectedIndex].Cells[0] is not null. If it is not, the last thing would be to make sure that the Value is not null, because you can't cast null to int. If this is the case, you should use int,TryParse or Convert.ToInt32 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a76a1x.aspx)

Comment: i did that,and i also double checked it,`GetCustomerId` is never -1 it allways has value

Comment: I am not sure about that. If this line throws NullReferenceException, something there is null when it is thrown, and the possibilities are the ones  listed. Please make sure you check all variables one by one at the time exception is thrown.

Comment: when that line finishes in this line it happens `Application.Run(new Form1());`

Comment: No, not really, it just bubbles up there. Can you upload a sample somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I guess i needed to use a telerik form instead of  VS form